# What is the Apple Pay URL scheme?

Tags: email, url-scheme, applepay

Apple has a list of official URL schemes so that you can link to Facetime, SMS, Maps, and iTunes using a URL from an email or web page.

[About Apple URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

I want to be able to direct people to Apple Pay. I do not need to charge them, and am not trying to collect payment for anything. I just want to open the Apple Pay app with a click from an email.

How do you open Apple Pay with a click from an email or web page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The URL scheme for Wallet (Passbook and Apple Pay together) is `shoebox://`, but that is officially an 'undocumented API' ([source](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2013/10/launch-center-pro-undocumented-urls-apple-apps.html)).

If you're trying to open the screen to initiate a payment, I believe that is possible only with a native app implementation and a lot of other back-end configuration.

Comment: Thanks! No, I'm not trying to initiate any type of payment. I just want the wallet to open when you click a link.

Comment: In that case, I believe `shoebox://` is your ticket! Feel free to come back and mark the answer after you've had a chance to try it out.

Comment: just confirmed that `shoebox://` also works with the Shortcuts app. But seriously, Shoebox? How? Why? If Apple Pay/Wallet is Shoebox, what is Numbers?